# how to exclude .php file from APC cache?

Tags: php, caching, apc

I cache top users data in a file named top_users.php, let us call it file cache.

But the APC will cache all the .php files, how to exclude some special .php file from APC

cache?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use filters in your apc config file:

```
apc.filters = "-/usr/share/files/.*"
```

This would not cache files under that match that pattern basically any file under that path /usr/share/files/

For you, you could use:

```
apc.filters = "-/my/share/top_users\.php"
```

Check this out http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.filters

This assumes the file is being required or included by absolute path.